# How would a single script truncate a particular table in every database?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Microsoft SQL Server 2008 with many databases and most of them have a Logs table. I would like to be able to schedule a script to run and truncate the Logs table in every one of these databases (dynamically). I imagine I have to get the name of every user database then truncate the table Logs in the databases that contain a Logs table.

The statement I ended up using is:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'Use [?]; IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = "Logs" and type="U")TRUNCATE TABLE Logs'
```

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server (Enterprise, Express, Standard)?

Comment: Standard Edition 64-bit, Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit of hack, since the stored procedure is undocumented, but try this:

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'Use ?; TRUNCATE TABLE Logs'
```

Comment: It wasn't me, I am still testing.

Comment: here is a good example to run to try this out (if you don't want to truncate a table): EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'Use ?;  print db_name()'

Comment: Toddler at the mouse syndrome :( I initialy read this as transaction logs you cant truncate in 2008 so it wouldnt resolve that issue.

Comment: I testing using the statement "EXEC sp_MSForEachDB 'Use ?; SELECT * FROM Logs'" This sort of worked for a sec. and then started returning errors. (Invalid object name) I then tried the actual statement on a development system and it errors out with no changes to the DB. (Cannot find the object..) Msg 4701

Comment: I think the catch is that not every database contains the proper table.

Comment: You can add an 'if exists' guard around it.

Comment: Facepalm, Thanks, That took care of it.

Answer (score -1):

In 2008 the easiest thing to do if if its not in production use at the time is this

Write a script that does this in dynamic sql

```
Alter Database <mydb> set recovery simple
go

Checkpoint
go

Alter Database <mydb> set recovery full
go
```

Comment: I definitely should have picked a less ambiguous table name.

Comment: He's not looking to truncate the Transaction Log, but rather to truncate a table called Logs.